# How does an NMOS transistor enter the triode region?

Tags: transistors, nmos

in my book it states that a transistor is in the triode mode when the gate to drain voltage is greater than the threshold voltage or equivalently when the drain to source voltage is less than the difference between gate to source voltage - threshold voltage. My question is, how do these two conditions depend on each other? How does VGD> Vtn cause Vds < Vov? I’ve been looking at the diagram and trying to understand it but I don’t see the relationship. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Y42.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VGD> Vtn doesn't *cause* Vds < Vov. However in many circuits,the loading on the drain (e.g. resistors) means that as VGS increases, VDS does decrease, and ultimately may lead to VGD > VTH.